# How does ActiveRecord not require the database connection to be passed in to finder methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, dependency-injection

When I invoke find() method on a model (MyModel.find(:all, :conditions => '...')), I do not have to pass a database connection as a parameter.

How does this work? What technique does Rails use to make this possible? Does it use dependency injection?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The database connection is defined in database.yml. During startup - Rails passes the connection to ActiveRecord::Base. As all the models are inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base they become 'aware' of what connection to use.

Take a look at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html